# Is "J'en ai" ever used in French?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

According to grammar books, we must always use a numeral in the answer to the question which mentions something for the first time, e. g. *Avez vous un stylo? - J'en ai un*.

But do we need the numeral if we are talking about a concrete object: *Avez vous le stylo?*? Can we say *J'en ai.* in this case? Or is such a conversation non-idiomatic?

Comment: J'en ai du bon, du bon et puis du bon, bon....  Pas avec *le* stylo mais un stylo.

Comment: *Avez-vous le/mon stylo ?* The most idiomatic answer would probably be a plain *oui*. If you really want to be over precise, then you could say  *Oui, je l'ai*, using *le* and not *en* since the object is identified.

Comment: Thank's a lot, None.

Answer (score 7):

For the countable case of the *stylo*, you couldn't say just *j'en ai*. But in other cases, depending on the context, and if it's uncountable, you might get away with *j'en ai*.

Some examples and variations (informal but mainstream "*tu as*"):

> *tu as de l'eau? - oui, j'en ai*.
>
> *tu as du saumon? - oui, j'en ai*.
>
> *tu as des briques? - oui, j'en ai plein/beaucoup*.
>
> *tu as ce livre? - oui, je l'ai*.
>
> *tu as **ton** cahier/stylo? - oui, je **l**'ai*.
>
> *tu as **un** cahier/stylo? - oui, j'en ai **un***.
>
> *tu as assez d'argent? - oui, j'en ai assez*.

Comment: For «le stylo», you can say «Je l'ai», right? just like «ce livre»?

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, you can - I'll add it to the list of examples. Except, if the question asks _as-tu **un** stylo?_ in which case you have to answer _j'en ai **un**_.

Answer (score 0):

**A**

> According to grammar books, we must always use a numeral in the answer to the question which mentions something for the first time, e. g. Avez vous un stylo? - J'en ai un.

"Un" is not a numeral (that is a numeral pronoun) but an indefinite pronoun in the present case; it is a numeral pronoun only if the locutor stresses "un" or if the context shows differently (it can be ambiguous).

If you are talking about a concrete object, it can be uncountable or countable.

**I** When the concrete object  is countable singular and has a determiner that is indefinite (singular) you use "j"en ai un(e)"; this form can also be used in the case of certain abstract entities but in certains cases it might not be idiomatic, and so one has to be very careful for abstract entities.

- — As-tu une *voiture* ? Oui, j'en ai une. (*concrete*)
- — Avez-vous une *façon* de faire particulière ? — J'en ai une. (*abstract*)
- — A-t-il une *permission* ? — Il en a bien une, mais pas pour aujourd'hui. (*abstract*)
- EXCEPTION — As-tu une envie de tout refaire ? — J'ai bien une envie de tout refaire, mais je ne veux pas le faire maintenant. (*abstract*) (*"J'en ai une." is not idiomatic.*)

**II** When the concrete object, or for that matter the abstract entity, is not countable (partitive determiner) you can use "j'en ai" (You can also use adverbs and pronouns in combination with this formula.) .

- — Avez-vous de la monnaie ? — Oui, j'en ai.   (*concrete*)
  (— Non je n'en ai pas trop.)
- — Avez-vous du temps pour ça ? — J'en ai, mais pas beaucoup.  (*abstract*)
- — Avez-vous de la patience ? — Non, je n'en ai pas. (*abstract*)
- — As-tu de la nourriture ? — Oui, j'en ai. '*concrete*)

**III** When the object is countable plural and has a determiner that is indefinite plural you also use "j"en ai".

- — As-tu des informations sur ce sujet ? — J'en ai, mais très peu.  (*abstract*)
  ( j'en ai très peu.)
- — Ont-ils des animaux de compagnie ? — Ils en ont, et même plus que les gens en ont d'habitude.  (*concrete*)
  (— Ils en ont quelques uns.)
- — As-tu des instruments de dessinateur ? Non, je n'en ai pas. (*concrete*)

*Exceptions*

- A-t-il de bonnes habitudes ? — Il a de bonnes habitudes. (*context of the totality, indefinite determiner ("Are all of his habits commendable?"*)
- — A-t-elle quand même de bonnes habitudes en plus de tous les actes routiniers réprimandables qu'elle effectue et dont elle ne se débarrasse pas ?  — Elle en a, mais peu. (*context of restriction*)
- —  As-tu de bons outils ?  — Oui, j'ai de bons outils. (*context of the totality: all my tools are good tools*)
- — As-tu de bons outils ? — J'en ai, mais certains ne sont pas de la meilleure qualité. (*context of restriction: some are good but not all.*)

**B**

> But do we need the numeral if we are talking about a concrete object: Avez vous le stylo?? Can we say J'en ai. in this case? Or is such a conversation non-idiomatic?

Since you are using the definite article "le" in the question it follows that "stylo" does not represent something indeterminate for the interlocutor, or in other words an indefinite pen; it is a specific pen, and the interlocutor is aware of that or otherwise "le" could not be used; therefore the interlocutor if he/she is speaking of that particular pen,shows that by using the definite article "le" (the form "l'" of this article  in this case) or a "pronom personnel" that refers to it ("le", (the form "l'" of the pronoun  in this case)). "J'en ai", where "en"  is used only for uncountabe entities or countable entities in the plural, and bar exception "en" must fulfill a function of "de", which cannot be the case. So you must answers as follows.

- — (Oui,) je l'ai *or*  — Oui

♦ (*other option*) — (Oui,) j'ai le stylo

or

- —(Non,) je (ne) l'ai pas. *or* — Non

♦ (*other option*) — (Non,) je n'ai pas le stylo (informel) (Non,) j'ai pas le stylo.

As situations are sometimes complex the answer might still be "j'en ai un".
In such a situation, the interlocutor might not know anymore what that particular pen is or if he/she knows that pen is not available to him/her, and he/she still wants to tell the person asking, that even if *the* pen is not available there is still *a* pen that can be used; this might be done directly without referring to the pen that both know about. In this sort of answer "un" will usually be stressed, however, stressed "un" in this case is not the numeral pronoun, it is the *indefinite pronoun*.

Comment: Abusive downvoting; there is no comment as to what could be wrong, and there is much in this answer that is bound to be true and helpful.

Comment: J'ai l'impression que les habitués de stackExchange French Language se soient lancés dans des querelles d'ego. Certes en tant que curieux du site j'aime lire des réponses concises mais je ne vois pas comment on peut justifier de downvote les plus étayées, quand bien même elle comporterait un léger point de divergence d'opinion.
Cela fait plusieurs fois que je remarque ce downvote abusif. Vous êtes libres de vous crêper le chignon en commentaire mais merci de ne pas vous laisser aller à des enfantillages qui trahissent l'esprit d'entraide du site.

Comment: @Hippo Pour ce qui est de la forme, j'aurais utilisé l'indicatif plutôt que le subjonctif : *j'ai l'impression que les habitués se **sont** lancés dans des querelles d'ego*. Pour ce qui est du fond, ton commentaire est exagéré et quelque peu condescendant. Après tout, cette réponse n'a reçu qu'un seul vote négatif alors qu'elle a peut-être été lue par 248 utilisateurs. Disons que cette réponse n'est ni *useful*, ni *not useful* pour la majorité des (non-)votants.

Comment: Je ne saurai jamais te remercier assez pour ta bienveillance et ton expertise dans la correction de ma conjugaison. Ça c'était condescendant. 
J'ai juste voulu pointer du doigt une tendance que j'ai cru remarquer dans plusieurs posts. Je trouve ça d'extrême mauvaise foi et trop finaliste que de statuer sur l'utilité de la réponse uniquement sur les votes qui lui ont été ou non attribués. 
Vous ne vous mouillez absolument pas en contournant le problème mis en lumière et le balayez sous couvert d'exagération.

Comment: Il est évident qu'il y a eu une certaine forme d'acharnement contre lui de la part de certains membres de la communauté. Les downvotes utilisés pour discréditer ses réponses, même lorsque celles-ci sont clairement bien documentées et utiles, sont une preuve tangible de cet acharnement. De toute manière j'ai vu que son compte avait été suspendu jusqu'à l'année prochaine, j'imagine que vous devez être fiers et arborer un sourire vainqueur derrière votre écran. C'est pathétique.

Comment: @Hippo Tu te trompes de combat. Il te manque l'historique de cet utilisateur sur FSE (et sur d'autres sites) pour comprendre la situation. S'il y a eu acharnement, c'est en premier lieu de sa part, principalement un acharnement à nier l'évidence. Il a d'ailleurs toujours eu de nombreux downvotes, c'est même depuis des années notre champion en absolu et le deuxième en relatif. Tu devrais aussi éviter les attaques personnelles. Comme tu l'as justement écrit, l'esprit du site est l'entraide. PS: Si tu réponds à quelqu'un dans un commentaire, n'oublie pas de mettre @ suivi de son pseudo.

Comment: @Hippo Juste comme une petite pièce du puzzle - pas une justification!, et je n'ai rien à voir dans la suspension de LPH, cet auteur détient la plupart des plus mauvais scores, et le plus souvent parce que les réponses étaient assez objectivement _fausses_ à propos de la langue française, et sans possibilité de faire changer LPH d'avis, quand bien même plusieurs francophones natifs pointaient les erreurs.

Comment: @Frank Il était l'un des utilisateurs avec le plus de reach du forum. Alors évidemment quand on a 2000 réponses au compteur, on est plus facilement sujet au downvote que si on n'en poste pas, c'est statistique. Dites-vous quand-même que je j'ai cliqué sur l'une de ses activités au hasard total, et il souffrait déjà de ce problème de downvote sans explication en 2018!

Comment: @Hippo Les votes sont anonymes même aux yeux des modérateurs. Les downvotes n'ont pas besoin d'être accompagnés d'un commentaire, spécialement quand on sait qu'ils ne serviront à rien car la personne qui les reçoit s'en fiche et ne modifie jamais ses réponses (hors parfois quelques coquilles).

Comment: Je comprends mal ta référence aux statistiques. Quand on a 2000 réponses au compteur, on n'est pas plus sujet aux downvotes que quand on en a peu. C'est même le contraire qui est observé. Plus les utilisateurs sont prolifiques, plus leur taux de downvote est réduit. Les 177 utilisateurs ayant le plus posté sur FSE (LPH exclu) ont 2.4 % de downvotes, les 245 suivants ont 6.5 % de downvotes. C'est le contenu des réponses et des questions qui motive les votants, pas le nombre de posts.

Comment: LPH a lui un taux downvote de 32 %. Il ne supprime jamais ses réponses même quand elles sont unanimement rejetées, c'est aussi ce qui explique son taux. Quand on efface une réponse, les points de réputation associés disparaissent.
Tu as aujourd'hui quatre réponses avec 13 upvotes et 0 downvotes, je ne peux que t'encourager à continuer sur cette lancée plutôt que de chercher à défendre une cause perdue.